# Google Apps Script - Randomizing Dropdown - Selecting Index

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

What I have seems simple, but looking through SO and other sites hasn't let me figure it out.

**H3** and **S3** are cells with a dropdown data validation list.

I have a button to randomize my these. This is easy when it's a number, but these are strings.
S3 is the cell for size so I have this randomized.

```
var randSize = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 1 + 1)) + 1
ss.getRange("S3").setValue(randSize)
```

I don't understand how to either set a random int to select the value based on array index. Or get a random string value based on the entries in cell **H3**, then setting **H3** to equal the new string.

```
Name        |     #
random item | random #
```

I need a random item to be set randomly from a value from H3.

Comment: If you're strings are  in an array then you can easily randomize there index and then output them with join

Comment: the values are in another tab just in a column. Data Validation made the dropdown menu. I prob shouldnt have said array, cause I dont even know if its storing those values in an array. I really dont know what Im doing yet overall.

Comment: You could rearrange them in the  column by creating a 2d array or you could validate from a list.  There are many possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue and solution:

If I understand you correctly, you have a set of string values in a column, and you want to copy a random value from that column to the cell `H3`.

If that's correct, you can just do the following:

- Retrieve the column values to a simple array via [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).
- Retrieve a random value from that array, using [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) and [Math](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math).
- Set that value to your target cell, using [setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue).

#### Code sample:

```
function getRandomValue() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // If standalone, use openById/openByUrl
  const sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("COLUMN_VALUES_SHEET_NAME");
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("H3_SHEET_NAME");
  const COLUMN_INDEX = 3; // Change according to your preferences
  const FIRST_ROW = 2; // Change according to your preferences
  const NUM_ROWS = sourceSheet.getLastRow() - FIRST_ROW + 1;
  const array = sourceSheet.getRange(FIRST_ROW, COLUMN_INDEX, NUM_ROWS).getValues().flat();
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
  const randomValue = array[randomIndex];
  targetSheet.getRange("H3").setValue(randomValue);
}
```